# best practice after upgrading the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, upgrade

Greetings ...

I need to know what anyone should do after upgrading the kernel ? How to do quick check if the kernel is suited for the server's softwares  , check whether if kernel is compilable with cpanel that currently installed etc .

Comment: All that should have been tested on a test machine.

Comment: +1 for the test machine - you really don't want experimenting with new kernels on production servers

Comment: I like the idea of doing all this after the fact on the production system - brings back some much needed suspense into daily routine... :)

Comment: After you upgrade you should reboot and start using it

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that you could try to use qemu snapshot option and some config imitating your original server config.